# Trying to add data to add data to an existing field in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, csv, load

I have been try to add data to one field in a table using a csv file
I have tried

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'PATH\\NEWDATATIMES.CSV' 
INTO TABLE trn_dacs (DateTime) 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '," 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\N';
```

I have tried several variations of this. This should be easy.  All the data is only going into one column.  I keep getting syntax errors, 1064 and 4200

Comment: Can you format your code and add sample data?
Somebody else formatting your code will lead to mistakes (Take the intro on using stackoverflow)

Comment: Are you doing some kind of Hadoop HIVE things here, because your query is similar..., if yes then add HIVE tag to your question, otherwise your question will be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in mismatched quotes when you specify the field terminator

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'PATH\\NEWDATATIMES.CSV' 
INTO TABLE trn_dacs (DateTime) 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\N';
```

Comment: Just comment and VTC as a typo, no need for a full answer.

Comment: My apologies the " in the question was a typo on my part, I did have the correct syntax.

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\0_Paul\\NEWDATATIMES.CSV' 
INTO TABLE trn_dacs (DateTime);            That worked....leaving off the fields and lines....thanks for your time